# converting $.each to native javascript - best approach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this which I want to convert to native JavaScript. What is the best approach?

```
$.each(data.results, function (i, val) {
    var venueObj = val.venue;
    if ((venueObj && venueObj.lat != 0)) {
        meetupName.push(val.name);
        meetupDescript.push(val.description);
        meetupUrl.push(val.event_url);

        //meetupLat = [];
        meetupLat.push(venueObj['lat']);
        //meetupLong = [];
        meetupLon.push(venueObj['lon']);

        //address
        meetupAddress.push(venueObj['address_1'] + "</h3><h3>" + venueObj['city']);
    } else {
        return;
    }    
});
```

Comment: `for-loop.......` or `data.results.forEach(function(){//})`

Comment: for loop is the best idea..

Comment: i try that, but i dont get the value i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should omit the "return" in your loop

```
for(var i in data.results) {
    var val = data.results[i]
    var venueObj = val.venue;
    if ((venueObj && venueObj.lat != 0)) {
        meetupName.push(val.name);
        meetupDescript.push(val.description);
        meetupUrl.push(val.event_url);

        //meetupLat = [];
        meetupLat.push(venueObj['lat']);
        //meetupLong = [];
        meetupLon.push(venueObj['lon']);

        //address
        meetupAddress.push(venueObj['address_1'] + "</h3><h3>" + venueObj['city']);
    }    
}
```